# Перезапись приложения, обновление, запуск

Tags: c#, winforms, обновление

Всем привет, есть ТЗ согласно которому я должен 
 Из приложения сам файл приложения (.exe) обновить т. е. перезаписать 
 а потом запустить обновленную версию, 
 
Собственно вопрос, как сделать перезапись файла с которого работает приложение, 
 и последующий запуск.

 Не понимаю как это возможно даже при помощи потоков т к приложение при перезаписи падает - что логично. 
Может я неправильно понял ТЗ 
**ТЗ**

> Структура каталогов: 
>   -Y:\new
>   -Y:\new\test.exe
>   -Y:\test.exe
>  При запуске программы должно появиться окно с информацией о версии файла и кнопкой «Обновить».
>  При нажатии
>   кнопки «Обновить» необходимо заменить файл «Y:\test.exe» файлом
>   «Y:\new\test.exe». 
>  После успешной замены файла необходимо
>   запустить программу заново.
>
> Программы «Y:\new\test.exe» и «Y:\test.exe» идентичны друг другу за
>   исключением версий файлов. Версии файлов «Y:\test.exe» и
>   «Y:\new\test.exe» должны быть разными. ...

Comment: Если обновление при запуске, то почему бы не настроить ClickOnce в проекте, там это уже из коробки реализовано, обновляться можно хоть локально, хоть с веба, как настроите. Проверка версий встроенная, если версии совпадают, обновление не произойдет. Если в ручную - проще всего лаунчер, который и обновления проверит, и программу запустит. Окно лаунчера использовать для вывода информации о наличии обновлений и соответствующих кнопок.

Comment: @rdorn да что то с батинком не пошло, сейчас попробую click или лаунчер, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Перезаписать файл, который бежит, невозможно.

Я бы делал такое следующим образом:

1. Создал утилиту (назовём её `updater`) без UI, которая получает на вход process id и два имени файлов.
2. В момент, когда нужно обновиться, создал бы файл `Y:\new\test.exe`, запустил бы `updater` (передав ему свой process id и пути `Y:\test.exe` и `Y:\new\test.exe`.
3. Updater должен дождаться завершения процесса, скопировать (или переместить, это смотря по ТЗ) файл `Y:\new\test.exe` в файл `Y:\test.exe` (напомню, он получает пути как аргументы командной строки), и запустить снова файл `Y:\test.exe`.

То есть updater должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 3)
        return -1;
    var id = int.Parse(args[0]);
    Process oldProcess = null;
    try
    {
        oldProcess = Process.GetProcessById(id);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // уже успел завершиться
    }
    if (oldProcess != null)
    {
        var exited = oldProcess.WaitForExit(10000); // ждём 10 сек
        if (!exited)
            return 1;
    }
    File.Copy(args[1], args[2], overwrite: true);
    Process.Start(args[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

(но добавьте контроль ошибок)

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Answer (score 0):

Ответ единственный и он прост делаю .bat файл с инструкциями который будет копировать после закрытия проги и запускать новую, всем удачи)

Функция которая создает бат исполняет и удаляет

```
private void MakeUpdate ()
        {
            string oldFileDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string UpdFileDir = Path.Combine( oldFileDir , "new\\test.exe");
            string bathcPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "111.bat").Replace("\\\\", "\\");

            string copy = String.Format("xcopy {0} /H /Y {1}\\", UpdFileDir, oldFileDir).Replace("\\\\","\\");
            string path = String.Format("path {0}\\", oldFileDir).Replace("\\\\", "\\");
            string del = String.Format("del {0}", bathcPath);

            string[] commands = new string[]
            {  "Timeout /T 2 /Nobreak",
                "cls", copy, path, "start test.exe", del};

            string txtDir = Path.Combine(oldFileDir, "111.txt");

            File.Create(txtDir).Close();
            File.WriteAllLines(txtDir, commands);
             File.Move(txtDir, Path.ChangeExtension(txtDir, ".bat"));
            Process.Start(bathcPath);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```