# Как перезаписать файл?(Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу )

Tags: c#, update

Всем привет) есть приложение, которое при вызове метода должна брать другой exe(идентичный этому просто с другой версией), и заменить себя им. После успешной замены нужно запустить файл заново.

Как обойти то, что исходный файл занят процессом, и при выполнении его нельзя перезаписать?

Comment: Файл А качает файл В, запускает его и закрывается. Файл В пытается закрыть А, если тот еще не закрылся, затем копирует себя в А, заменяя старый А.

Comment: Можете использовать стороннюю утилиту Handle от SysInternals (ответ с SO-En - https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows о том как найти какой процесс открыл файл, и #2 - командная утилита для закрытия в другом процессе - https://superuser.com/questions/335138/how-to-close-all-file-handles-under-a-given-folder-programatically). Только учтите что если у вас нет прав на запись в другой процесс то никакая утилита вам не поможет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак, файл, который относится к бегущему процессу, удалить невозможно.

Напишите маленькую программу, которая заменяет один файл на другой, запустите её, пусть она дождётся окончания работы вашего процесса (дайте ей ещё и PID) и подменит файл.

Comment: Вот тут есть готовый код: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671508/10105

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли)

Comment: @MrStacky: Пожалуйста! Очень рад!